# how to access snap filesystem (/tmp)

Tags: mount, snap, 22.10

Please tell me a way to copy a file from snap:/tmp to the main file system. Currently snap:/tmp is a .tmp file located in /run/snapd/ns.
Additionally is there a way to mount snap entier root?

Comment: i need copy file placed under /tmp of snap application to my main file system. That actual problem. Pretty simple i guess, but i can't see a simple solution. ubuntu version fixed thanks.

Comment: there are already several ways to influence snap and main os on each other. In answer to your question, I needed intermediate files of working compiler. I've already got them using a different machine, it's probably not the best idea to use a snap for compiler, or use containerization without being able to connect to the guest file system. Anyway, this is a philosophical debate, but then I needed a working solution.